# sql server lock - null pointer exception with ws portal

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, websphere, websphere-portal

There is a SSIS job that runs and updates an employee table, during which a null pointer exception is seen in the portal logs, when portal queries the table. The table gets locked completely. Neither  Is this to do with a setting/configuration in SQL server or something that needs to be done at portal?

Additional info:
The lock is in effect during a series of insert, update and delete actions on the table which are run in a batch.

about 1500-2500 individual statements which are a mix of below

insert into table .... 
update table.. where condition on pk
delete table.. where condition on pk

Comment: We would need to see the source of the TSQL to fix it.

Comment: @hogan added some info. Thanks.

Comment: Need more detail -- this tells me nothing.